# Group by and sum not working on newly created columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set which looks like follows (Values changed):

```
Value   A   B
ABC     20  5
ABC     20  5 
ABC     20  5
ABC     20  5
XYZ     20  5
XYZ     20  5
XYZ     20  5
```

I create a new column C using

```
df['C'] = df['A']/df['B']
```

I obtain the df:

```
Value   A   B   C
ABC     20  5       4
ABC     20  5       4
ABC     20  5       4
ABC     20  5       4
XYZ     20  5       4
XYZ     20  5       4
XYZ     20  5       4
XYZ     20  5       4
```

Until here everything works fine. Now When I try to use group by on the df, it doesn't give the sum of the third column(the one I created). I am using the following code line for group by

```
df.groupby('Value').sum()
```

The result is:

```
Value   A   B
ABC    60   15
XYZ    60   15
```

Any reason why it might be doing that?

Comment: Doing what? `print(df.groupby('Value').sum())` works just fine for me.

Comment: You need to assign your `groupby` back to your dataframe, i.e. `df = df.groupby('Value').sum()`. `groupby` is not an in-place calculation.

Comment: @jpp Why would that be a specific problem for column C? The OP has to elaborate, what doesn't work.

Comment: @Mr. T I have not shared the original data set. But basically it isn't giving me the sum of columns created by me/ or which weren't there in the df originally.

Comment: @A.DS But is the problem reproducible with your toy dataset in the question? If not, people can't suggest solutions.

Comment: @Mr. T Makes sense. Unfortunately unable to replicate a data set, which would behave similarly.

Comment: Well, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is necessary to analyze the problem. Though it is difficult to understand, why you can't copy a couple of rows from your dataset and change the values, if the data are not meant to be published. And no error messages? What does appear in `C` then? Maybe this will give people an idea, what the underlying problem is.

Comment: @Mr. T It is just eliminating the columns that I created. Modified the post as well for a clearer picture.

Comment: Sounds like this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37575944/8881141